# Unable to Defrag Windows 10 instance in VMWare on SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 12 Pro on a Windows 7 Pro host which is using a single SSD.

On VMWare I have a Windows 10 Pro installation, which I backup at least twice a week to different NAS boxes as it is my primary work environment.

The instance has 80Gb of space allocated, of which (according to the W10 instance) 60Gb is being used... however, the physical size of the files on the host is now well over 70Gb.  Especially after recent W10 upgrades, where I've removed the upgrade files via "clean up".

I've tried using the "defrag and compact" options on VMWare to try and reclaim the 12Gb+ of space, but it doesn't do a thing.  And because the host is using an SSD, the W10 instance does not allow defragging to take place.

Is there any way for me to run a defrag on the W10 instance, so that my backup is smaller?

(I'm aware that it is not a good idea to defrag an SSD, and I do understand why... however, this is not going to be something I do on a regular basis!)

Answer (score 2):

Defragging virtual disk from inside the VM won't decrease file size on host. It will rather grow even more. That's because host (or more precisely: VM software aka. hypervisor) doesn't understand filesystem inside and doesn't know which data can be discarded.

There's an [official article on VMware support page](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_disk_shrink.html) that describes correct procedure to achieve your goal. There's a bunch of requirements:

> The shrink feature is not enabled if the virtual machine
>
> - Contains a snapshot
> - Is a parent of a linked clone
> - Is a linked clone
>
> The shrink feature is not enabled for a virtual machine if any of its
>   virtual disks are
>
> - Preallocated when created
> - Not used in independent-persistent mode
> - Legacy disks that are not in persistent mode
> - Booted as independent disks

There's also an implied requirement that VMware Tools have to be installed on guest.

The process is based on cooperation between VMware Tools and hypervisor. VMware Tools analyze disk structure from guest's perspective (so they have insight into actual filesystem structure) and report them to hypervisor, so that it can discard unused sectors.

Here are steps for Windows guest (cited from linked article):

> 1. Double-click the VMware Tools icon in the system tray.
> 2. Click the Shrink tab.
>
>    [image: Screenshot of the Shrink tab]
> 3. Select the virtual disks you want to shrink, then click Prepare to Shrink. A dialog box tracks the progress of the wiping process.
> 4. Click Yes when VMware Tools finishes wiping the selected disk partitions. A dialog box tracks the progress of the shrinking process. Shrinking disks may take considerable time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my VMware Tools does not give the dialog you've shown. Instead I get an "About VMware Tools" dialog for Version 10.1.6 build 5214329. I can see no way to get the tabbed dialog, which I recognise from my old Windows 7 instance that I used years ago

Comment: I've tried doing a re-install/repair on the tools, rebooted the VM, but I still get the same "about" dialog, not the tabbed one

Comment: I've discovered one option is to use `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\VMWareToolboxCmd.exe` via command line, using parameters `disk shrink c:\`.  So I will make that into a shortcut for future use

Comment: However, I'm giving you a +1 for reminding me that this is something that needs to be initiated from within the instance. I really don't get why they removed the easy way of doing it. Anyway, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @gonostaj for their answer, but unfortunately I was not presented with the tabbed dialog in my VMware Tools.

After a bit of searching, I discovered that the shrink can be done via the following command line on the guest instance instead...

```
C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tool\VMwareToolboxCmd.exe disk shrink c:\
```